# How does multiple for loops in the same scope affect a program's big O notation?

Tags: javascript, big-o

So let's say I had a program that looked like this:

```
var foo = 10;

for(var i = 0; i < foo; i++){
    console.log('first loop');
}

for(var j = 0 j < foo; j++){
    console.log('second loop');
}
```

Now, from what I understand about Big O notation in general, we measure the efficiency(aka how long it takes to run) of a program based on the size of the N input. So if the 'j' loop were nested within the 'i' loop, this would make it n^2, but because both loops are in the same scope, the runtime would still be O(N). Is this assessment correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your assumption is correct,

The basic operation done here in both loop is

- Loop 1, Iteration 1
- Loop 1, Iteration 2 
  .......
- Loop 1, Iteration 10
- Loop 2, Iteration 1 
  .......
- Loop 2, Iteration 10

for each loop of order N there is N write operation.

so total time complexity will be **O(N) + O(N)** but since constants are ignored so the complexity is **O(N)**

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is correct

just to point out that the phrase "how long it takes to run" is not 100% accurate for Big O

> describes the limiting behavior of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value or infinity.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

```
O(N) + O(N) = O(N)
O(N) + O(M) = O(max(N,M))
```

Answer (score 0):

This would still be linear to search through, O(N) as the two loops don't interact with each other at all.

Technically array access is constant O(1), its the search that is linear in time.

O notation is basically for measuring an algorithms complexity, scope doesn't matter here.

Comment: he meant "scope" to state that loops are not nested, but independent